# Adding Spring Boot-style Security tot non-Boot Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My goal is to add a OpenID Connect-based authentication layer (Using Azure AD) to a non-Boot Spring application. The required configuration is supplied as Java code for a Spring Boot application;

```java
// Config to be added to existing project
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AADOAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
    }
}
```

However, the application to-be extended with this functionality is

- Not a Spring Boot application

  The application *is* Spring framework based though, using Spring security as defined in XML configuration files defined in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`
- Not modifiable

  New classes or configuration can be added, but the core (3th party/vendored) cannot be changed

I've tried to have the configuration added to the project by defining

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.security"/>
```

in the spring XML configuration, and while I see the component is initialized, the `configure(..)`-member is never invoked and the authentication is not added the the application.

Is it possible to extend this (legacy) application with Spring Boot-based configuration? What would be the recommended way to add such functionality?

Comment: None of the code you've posted is unique to Spring boot, it's just the Spring Security configuration API and works fine without Spring boot. However, if you already have a Spring Security XML configuration, it's likely that they're clashing and perhaps the one defined in the XML is taking priority.